# merging 2 json into one single json with value parsing in bash.

Tags: json, bash, shell, sh, jq

I have two JSONS:

```
{
  "name": "paypal_modmon",
  "description": "Role For Paypal admin-service box",
  "run_list": [
      "recipe[djcm_paypal_win::sslVerify]"
    ]
  }
```

and

```
{
  "name": "paypal_dev",
  "default_attributes": {
    "7-zip": {
        "home": "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\\7-zip"
    },
    "modmon": {
        "env": "dev"
    },
    "paypal": {
        "artifact": "%5BINTEGRATION%5D"
    }
  },
  "override_attributes": {
    "default": {
        "env": "developmen"
    },
    "windows": {
      "password": "Pib1StheK1N5"
    },
    "task_sched":{
      "credentials": "kX?rLQ4XN$q"
    },
    "seven_zip": {
        "url": "https://djcm:Pib1StheK1N5@artifactory.dowjones.io/artifactory/djcm-zip-local/djcm/chef/paypal/7z1514-x64.msi"
    }
  },
  "chef_type": "environment"
}
```

I want to read the values from the second json : "default_attributes" and "override_attributes" and merge them with the first json into an output like :

```
{
  "description": "Role For Paypal admin-service box",
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[djcm_paypal_win::sslVerify]"
  ],
  "chef_type": "environment",
    "seven_zip": {
      "url": "https://djcm:Pib1StheK1N5@artifactory.dowjones.io/artifactory/djcm-zip-local/djcm/chef/paypal/7z1514-x64.msi"
    },
    "task_sched": {
      "credentials": "kX?rLQ4XN$q"
    },
    "windows": {
      "password": "Pib1StheK1N5"
    },
    "paypal": {
      "artifact": "%5BINTEGRATION%5D"
    },
    "modmon": {
      "env": "dev"
    },
    "7-zip": {
      "home": "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\\7-zip"
    },
    "default": {
      "env": "developmen"
    },
  "name": "paypal_modmon"
}
```

Is there a way to do this in bash and how would go to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. With jq seems super simple :

```
jq -s '.[0] + .[1].default_attributes + .[1].override_attributes' a-roles.json a-env.json > manifest.json
```

manifest.json ->

```
{
  "default": {
    "env": "developmen-jq"
  },
  "7-zip": {
    "home": "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\\7-zip"
  },
  "name": "paypal_modmon",
  "description": "Role For Paypal admin-service box",
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[djcm_paypal_win::sslVerify]"
  ],
  "seven_zip": {
    "url": "https://djcm:Pib1StheK1N5@artifactory.dowjones.io/artifactory/djcm-zip-local/djcm/chef/paypal/7z1514-x64.msi"
  },
  "task_sched": {
    "credentials": "kX?rLQ4XN$q"
  },
  "windows": {
    "password": "Pib1StheK1N5"
  },
  "paypal": {
    "artifact": "%5BINTEGRATION%5D"
  },
  "modmon": {
    "env": "dev"
  }
}
```

EDIT 1 :

I also need to parse out the run_list key value pair from a-roles.json and ignore all other info to have something:

```
{
  "default": {
    "env": "developmen-jq"
  },
  "7-zip": {
    "home": "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\\7-zip"
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[djcm_paypal_win::sslVerify]"
  ],
  "seven_zip": {
    "url": "https://djcm:Pib1StheK1N5@artifactory.dowjones.io/artifactory/djcm-zip-local/djcm/chef/paypal/7z1514-x64.msi"
  },
  "task_sched": {
    "credentials": "kX?rLQ4XN$q"
  },
  "windows": {
    "password": "Pib1StheK1N5"
  },
  "paypal": {
    "artifact": "%5BINTEGRATION%5D"
  },
  "modmon": {
    "env": "dev"
  }
}
```

is that possible with jq ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you're reading in multiple files, you should use the `--argfile` option so you can reference the contents of the file by name. And judging by the name of the attributes you wish to merge, you should be wary of the different merging options you have. `default_attributes` suggests it should be attributes that should be used if omitted. `override_attributes` suggests it should force it's values in.

```
$ jq --argfile merge input2.json \
'($merge.default_attributes * .) + $merge.override_attributes' input1.json
```

By merging the input with the `default_attributes` using `*`, it allows you to start with the defaults and add your actual values in place.  That way missing values end up being provided by the default object.

Then adding the `override_attributes` object, the values are completely replaced and not just merged.